# Google api client for pubsub unable to find topic

Tags: java, google-cloud-pubsub

I am attempting to use the java pubsub client to get a named topic:

```
@Value("projects/${pubsub.projectId}/topics/${environment}-events")
String topic;

Pubsub client = PubsubUtils.getClient();
        if (enabled) {
            logger.info("PubSub event logging: enabled");
            Topic t = null;
            try {
                t = client.projects().topics().get(topic).execute();
                if (t != null) {
                    logger.info("PubSub topic {} already exists. Continuing ...", topic);
                    return client;
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                logger.info("Failed to get topic: {}", topic, ex);
            }

            // create topic
            if (t == null) {
                createTopic(client);
            }
        } else {
            logger.info("PubSub event logging: disabled");
        }
```

Unfortunately when I run this with

```
String topic = "projects/projectid/topics/topicid";
```

I constantly get back a 404 response:

```
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The requested URL <code>/v1/projects%2Fbrightcove-rna-master%2Ftopics%2Fdev_achauhan-events</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>

    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1049)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at com.brightcove.collector.beans.PubSubProducerBean.createTopic(PubSubProducerBean.java:54)
    at com.brightcove.collector.beans.PubSubProducerBean.getPublisher(PubSubProducerBean.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 54 more
```

From the looks of it, the client library seems to be url escaping the topic name in the url and the google server is failing.

Is there a way to work around this or better yet a way to get google api client to not escape the topic name.

**EDIT** As requested, this is the full source:

```
@Value("projects/${pubsub.projectId}/topics/${environment}-events")
String topic;

Pubsub getPublisher() throws Exception {
    Pubsub client = PubsubUtils.getClient();
    if (enabled) {
        logger.info("PubSub event logging: enabled");
        Topic t = null;
        try {
            t = client.projects().topics().get(topic).execute();
            if (t != null) {
                logger.info("PubSub topic {} already exists. Continuing ...", topic);
                return client;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.info("Failed to get topic: {}", topic, ex);
        }

        // create topic
        if (t == null) {
            createTopic(client);
        }
    } else {
        logger.info("PubSub event logging: disabled");
    }
    return client;
}

Topic createTopic(Pubsub client) throws IOException {
    return client.projects().topics().create(topic, new Topic().setName(topic)).execute();
}
```

Comment: Which version of client library are you using?

Comment: Also, it seems like failing in createTopic, not get. Can you show the code for createTopic?

Comment: Updated the question with the full source.

Comment: I can not reproduce your issue. Can you confirm that the value of the `topic` is expected? Is it possible that the value is already percent encoded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any other Google api used in your project?
I just solved the problem.I use Google DataStore API and the jar google-http-client 1.15 encode the topic from '/' to '%2F' which is incorrect.
You can exclude google-http-client 1.15 from other Google APIs

```
Maven code:
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
```

Please use version 1.20 or later!
The correct topic as below.

```
<code>/v1/projects/brightcove-rna-master/topics/dev_achauhan-events</code>
```